# SCSS mixins materializecss

Tags: css, angularjs, sass, ng-animate, materialize

i'm trying to understand the mixing concept in the materializecss mixins found: http://materializecss.com/sass.html#mixins

I think the ones you'll need if you don't want to go to the page:

```
animation($args)
animation-delay($delay)
animation-direction($direction)
animation-duration($duration)
animation-fill-mode($mode)
animation-iteration-count($count)
animation-name($name)
animation-play-state($state)
animation-timing-function($function)
```

so say I'm using Animate.css and ngAnimate and I have the following animation:

```
&.ng-enter {
  -webkit-animation: slideInLeft 1s;
  -moz-animation: slideInLeft 1s;
  -ms-animation: slideInLeft 1s;
  animation: slideInLeft 1s;
}
&.ng-leave {
  -webkit-animation: slideOutLeft 1s;
  -moz-animation: slideOutLeft 1s;
  -ms-animation: slideOutLeft 1s;
  animation: slideOutLeft 1s;
}
```

how would this be in the mixin thingy?

Comment: What's your question exactly? If you're wondering how it works, the solution is actually on the link you shared: `&.ng-enter { @include animation(slideInLeft 1s); }`

Comment: yea that's it, I didn't know how the animation mixin works, so yea!